# Too much text in div doesn't write on a new line, but pushes whole div down to make space instead

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where my text isn't moving onto a new line when it reaches the edge of its parent div, but stretches the parent div downwards to make space width-wise. Two pictures are shown below illustrating the issue.

[image]

[image]

The HTML and appropriate CSS will be shown below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: Raleway;
}
.menu {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.section-one {
    display: inline-block;
}
.section-two {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
.block {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.float-left {
    float:left;
}
.float-right {
    padding-left: 2em;
    float:right;
}
.img-menu {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
.img-info {
    display: inline-block;
}
.h {
    padding-left:0.5em;
    color: #777;
}
.h-primary {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    color: black;
}
.h-secondary {
    margin-top: 0.25em;
}
.h-tertiary {
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div className='menu'>
    <div className='float-left'>
        {details.reduce(
        function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
            if (currentIndex % 2 === 0) { 
                var temp = array.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + 2)
                temp[0]['pair'] = true
                temp[1]['pair'] = false
                accumulator.push(temp)
            }
            return accumulator;
        }, []).map((pair) => 
        <div className='block'>
            {pair.map((detail) => 
            <div onclick="location.href='#';" className={['button', detail.pair ? 'float-left' : 'float-right'].join(' ')}>
                <img src={detail.imgsrc} className='img-menu' />
                <div className='img-info'>
                    <div>
                        <strong>
                            <h5 className='h h-primary'>
                                {detail.buttontitle}
                            </h5>
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h5 className='h h-secondary'>
                            {detail.buttonsubtitle}
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
        )}
    </div>
    <!-- Section with the issue! -->
    <div className='section-two float-left'>
        <div className='block'>
            <div>
                <strong>
                    <h5 className='h h-primary'>
                        Placeholder
                    </h5>
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h5 className='h h-tertiary '>
                    Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='block'>
            <h5 className='h h-primary'>
                PlaceholderButton
            </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your dynamic HTML is not relevant at all for the question. You don't even mention or tag it properly. Instead, add the *generated* HTML.

Comment: The element will need to be fixed in width for the text to wrap. Because it is an inline element, it will expand to fit the content and if it does not fit, it will drop below.